# How to select records from linked ManyToMany tables

Tags: java, hibernate

Two entities linked by the ManyToMany relation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    protected String code;

    @ManyToMany(CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "CATEGORY_ITEM",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    )
    protected Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Category category = (Category) o;
      return Objects.equals(code, category.code);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(code);
    }

}   

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    protected String code;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    protected Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Item item = (Item) o;
      return Objects.equals(code, item.code);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(code);
    }

}
```

I want to find a list of all items objects for a specific category.

So I need Item objects, and this information is only in the Category table, then I wrote such a query in CategoryRepository:

```
@Query("select i from Category c join с.items i where c.code = :code")
List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

As a result, I get an empty list.

Although if you read a specific object

```
Category сategory = CategoryRepository.getId(1);
```

if you extract a list from it, then the data is there

```
assertEquals(сategory.getItems().size(), 2);
```

I tried this option, but I still get an empty list:

```
@Query("select c.items from Category с i where c.code = :code")
List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

I tried to write a request on the Item Repository side and also an empty list:

```
@Query("select i from Item i join i.categories c where c.code = :code")
List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

I want to find a list of all items objects for a specific category.
How do I get this data?

Comment: There is no field named code in your Category entity. Check your query.

Comment: And also - do you have all getters and setters and a no-args constructor?

Comment: @Mar-Z, I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I have corrected and added code, including constructors, etc.

Comment: Try with `left join fetch` instead of just `join` in the query. Hibernate use lazy loading for many-to-many by default.

Comment: The code looks good, do you get any errors on the console?

Try to enable `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see how the `JPQL`s are being translated into `SQL`, it can help in debugging.

Comment: @atish.s, No, there are no mistakes. I just get an empty list. On Monday I will post the text of the JPQL query